# How to overload operator= used in initializing a new object?

Tags: c++, initialization, assignment-operator

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to understand how Class works. I made a simple example for myself when I encounter this problem. My class has one private property `num` and I'm trying to initialize it with an int this way: `Number one = Number::ONE;` but it doesn't work. However, when I do this it works fine: `Number one; one = Number::ONE`. I prefer the first option. Please help!

Here is my complete code:

```
class Number {
public:
    enum {ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR};
    Number();

    void print() const;

    Number& operator=(int);
private:
    int num;
};

Number& Number::operator=(int n) {
    num = n;
    return *this;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Number n = Number::ONE; // doesn't work :(
    n.print();

    return 0;
}

Number::Number() {
    num = 0;
}

void Number::print() const {
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to overload the assignment operator for what you are doing? Just make a mutator function.

Comment: int changeNum (enum x) { return your enum }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, when you write

```
Number one = Number::ONE;
```

the compiler will *not* use the assignment operator to initialize `one`. The `operator=` function is only invoked when you have an existing object that you want to reassign a new value. Instead, in this case, the compiler tries to invoke a *conversion constructor*, a constructor that takes in an object of the type on the right-hand side of the equality. Since you haven't defined a constructor like that, you're getting a compiler error.

One way to do this would be something like this:

```
class Number {
public:
     Number(int value); // <-- Conversion constructor
     ...
};

Number::Number(int value) {
    num = value;
}
```

Now, the code you've given here will compile properly.

You may want to do some reading into copy constructors, assignment operators, conversion constructors, and conversion assignment operators, since they're one of the trickier parts of routine C++ and often trip up people transitioning from basic C++ to more intermediate-level language techniques.

Comment: I believe I understand now how to use the conversion constructor, but what if I still want the object to be initialized this way, `Number one = Number::ONE` is there a way at all? thanks!

Comment: I believe that the conversion constructor is the way to do this.

Comment: @JS starter - a conversion constructor IS invoked that way, unless it is declared `explicit`.   So `Number one = Number::ONE` will invoke a constructor with argument of (the type of) `Number::ONE`

Comment: @templatetypedef   A constructor is usually better off using an initialiser list rather than assigning values in its body.   In your case it would be `Number::Number(int value) : num(value) {}`.   Among other things, this avoids initialising and then assigning members.   For members that are a class type, it also gives exception safety, which assigning in the constructor body (usually) does not.

Comment: @Peter Oh, absolutely. I chose to go this other route because I wasn't sure how familiar the OP was with initialization lists and didn't want to drop too many concepts into a single answer.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't overload the constructor to take an integer as parameter that is why you get the error:

```
class Number 
{
    public:
        enum {ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR};
        Number(int x) : num(x){}

    void print() const;

    Number& operator=(int);
private:
    int num;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, I finally understand it now!